# Insert non-duplicates to master table using MERGE/INSERT from Incremental table in Teradata

Tags: teradata, sql-insert, sql-merge

I came across a situation where there is a master table called MORTALITY (containing info regarding deceased individuals) And another table called INC_MORTALITY (incremental mortality) table which is refreshed on a weekly basis 
Note: **Both the tables have similar format**

So INC_MORTALITY has this week’s new records, containing both additional deceased individuals as well as updates of old data for previously delivered records. This is a single file with a column (OP_DIRECTIVE) specifying if it is an “add” or “delete” record.

Processing Weekly Files To incorporate the weekly update file: we need to Add rows in the master table which have OP_DIRECTIVE = 'A' as the operation in the weekly update.
I am currently using the below stmt to INSERT the records

```sql
INSERT INTO db.MORTALITY
    SELECT
    DATA_SOURCE,
    OP_DIRECTIVE,
    DD_IMP_FLAG,
    DOB,
    DOD,
    DEATH_VERIFICATION,
    GENDER_PROBABILITY,
    GENDER,
    TOKEN_1,
    TOKEN_2,
    TOKEN_4,
    TOKEN_5,
    TOKEN_7,
    TOKEN_16,
    TOKEN_KEY
    FROM db.INC_MORTALITY INC
    WHERE INC.OP_DIRECTIVE = 'A';
--The above Query fetches all the records to be added to the Master Table - MORTALITY(My Requirement) and for some reason if INC_MORTALITY is not refreshed after a week i will be updating the same records again to the master file.
```

Now have I updated `primary index (token_1, token_2)` in my table definition, i know it will throw an **ERROR** if we are trying to insert records with the same values of token_1 & token_2 but this will be an automated process and my job will **FAIL** if there is an **ERROR** so, i want it to check PRIOR to the Insert process if the records are already inserted, so that it will skip inserting duplicates
like using IFNOTEXISTS stmt

Adding to the above: Can i use `MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT` operation here like below:

```sql
MERGE db.MORTALITY B
USING (SELECT
    DATA_SOURCE,
    OP_DIRECTIVE,
    DD_IMP_FLAG,
    DOB,
    DOD,
    DEATH_VERIFICATION,
    GENDER_PROBABILITY,
    GENDER,
    TOKEN_1,
    TOKEN_2,
    TOKEN_4,
    TOKEN_5,
    TOKEN_7,
    TOKEN_16,
    TOKEN_KEY
    FROM db.INC_MORTALITY
    WHERE OP_DIRECTIVE = 'A') A
    ON  A.TOKEN_1 = B.TOKEN_1
    AND A.TOKEN_2 = B.TOKEN_2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (A.DATA_SOURCE,A.OP_DIRECTIVE,A.DD_IMP_FLAG,A.DOB,A.DOD,A.DEATH_VERIFICATION,A.GENDER_PROBABILITY,A.GENDER,A.TOKEN_1,A.TOKEN_2,A.TOKEN_4,A.TOKEN_5,A.TOKEN_7,A.TOKEN_16,A.TOKEN_KEY);
```

The above Query is executing fine in Teradata Studio but not inserting any records from INC_MORTALITY TO MORTALITY(master) table, am I doing anything wrong?

UPDATE:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MORTALITY;


CREATE MULTISET  TABLE MORTALITY,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    NO FALLBACK,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
(

    DATA_SOURCE          VARCHAR(25) NULL 
        TITLE 'Data Source',
    OP_DIRECTIVE         VARCHAR(25) NULL 
        TITLE 'Operation Directive',
    DD_IMP_FLAG          INTEGER NULL 
        TITLE 'Death Date Imputation Flag',
    DOB                  DATE NULL 
        TITLE 'Date Of Birth',
    DOD                  DATE NULL 
        TITLE 'Date Of Death',
    DEATH_VERIFICATION   INTEGER NULL 
        TITLE 'Death Verification',
    GENDER_PROBABILITY   FLOAT NULL 
        TITLE 'Gender Probability Score',
    GENDER               VARCHAR(25) NULL 
        TITLE 'Gender',
    TOKEN_1              VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 1',
    TOKEN_2              VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 2',
    TOKEN_4              VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 4',
    TOKEN_5              VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 5',
    TOKEN_7              VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 7',
    TOKEN_16             VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token 16',
    TOKEN_KEY            VARCHAR(44) NULL 
        TITLE 'Token Key'
)
    PRIMARY INDEX MORTALITY_IX1
     (
            TOKEN_1,
            TOKEN_2
     );
```

This is the Table DDL for MORTALITY and INC_MORTALITY also has similar format. 
The combination of both the columns TOKEN_1,TOKEN_2 identify a unique record and as you can see above all of them are NULLABLE columns
As i previously stated my very first INSERT stmt serves the purpose but i just want to avoid getting an error like this: `Duplicate unique prime key error in db.MORTALITY`, if the records are already inserted
I hope the information helps, Thanks

Comment: Does the combination (TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2) uniquely identify a row? MERGE requires matching on all PRIMARY INDEX fields at a minimum, but if those fields are only a subset of the unique PRIMARY KEY then you may wish to add more match conditions. Or perhaps can TOKEN_1 and/or TOKEN_2 be NULL?

Comment: Hi Fred, I've added an UPDATE section above to answer your question, because comment box has around 600 char limit

Comment: Your target table should be defined as SET plus a UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX, currently you won't get a *Duplicate unique prime key error*. As Fred said, if there are NULLs in those PI columns they will never MATCH and insert that row anyway

Comment: I would suggest either replacing the nulls with an empty string in your tables, or coalescing them with an empty string in your join. That way they will match correctly in your merge.

Comment: PI columns won't have NULLS, Earlier this table had no PI so I altered the table to have (TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2) as PI columns that's why TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2 are shown as NULLABLE columns. A little background on these columns: token_1 = (ln + f_initial + dob + gender) and token_2 = (soundex(ln) + soundex(fn) + dob + gender) so i believe these columns would have some value for each row

Comment: Hi Andrew can you elaborate?

Comment: If that is your exact table definition above, you cannot be getting a duplicate unique primary key error, because your primary key is not defined as unique.

Comment: My Apologies, MORTALITY has Unique Primary Index and INC_MORTALITY has just Primary Index. Now I altered MORTALITY to Primary Index(TOKEN_1,token_2). So now that i wont get an error, how can i possibly check for the records that are already inserted in my insert/merge statement!!

Comment: To return to your original question, provided that (TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2) is logically a unique "key" that does not change (and is not null) then there is nothing obviously incorrect. Can you clarify the issue, i.e. what you expect / want vs what is happening?

Comment: yes @Fred, my INSERT process is on schedule which runs every week and loads the data into MORTALITY table(master) from INC_MORTALITY and 1 week later INC_MORTALITY has data from the current week and previous week, so now i expect it to load only the current weeks data into MORTALITY. Any thoughts on how to check for the records that are already inserted in my master file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing SOME research myself and figured out the below approaches:

1) Using INSERT
This query worked for me, it inserts records only which are in INC_MORTALITY but not in MORTALITY (avoiding duplicates)

```sql
    INSERT INTO db.MORTALITY 
    SELECT * FROM db.INC_MORTALITY INC
    WHERE INC.OP_DIRECTIVE = 'A'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM db.MORTALITY_INDEX
```

2) Similarly using MERGE

```sql
MERGE db.MORTALITY MI
USING (SELECT
    DATA_SOURCE,
    OP_DIRECTIVE,
    DD_IMP_FLAG,
    DOB,
    DOD,
    DEATH_VERIFICATION,
    GENDER_PROBABILITY,
    GENDER,
    TOKEN_1,
    TOKEN_2,
    TOKEN_4,
    TOKEN_5,
    TOKEN_7,
    TOKEN_16,
    TOKEN_KEY
    FROM db.INC_MORTALITY
    WHERE OP_DIRECTIVE = 'A') INC
    ON  MI.DATA_SOURCE        = INC.DATA_SOURCE
    AND MI.DD_IMP_FLAG        = INC.DD_IMP_FLAG
    AND MI.DOB                = INC.DOB
    AND MI.DOD                = INC.DOD
    AND MI.DEATH_VERIFICATION = INC.DEATH_VERIFICATION
    AND MI.GENDER_PROBABILITY = INC.GENDER_PROBABILITY
    AND MI.GENDER             = INC.GENDER
    AND MI.TOKEN_1            = INC.TOKEN_1
    AND MI.TOKEN_2            = INC.TOKEN_2
    AND MI.TOKEN_4            = INC.TOKEN_4
    AND MI.TOKEN_5            = INC.TOKEN_5
    AND MI.TOKEN_7            = INC.TOKEN_7
    AND MI.TOKEN_16           = INC.TOKEN_16
    AND MI.TOKEN_KEY          = INC.TOKEN_KEY
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (DATA_SOURCE,
        OP_DIRECTIVE,
        DD_IMP_FLAG,
        DOB,
        DOD,
        DEATH_VERIFICATION,
        GENDER_PROBABILITY,
        GENDER,
        TOKEN_1,
        TOKEN_2,
        TOKEN_4,
        TOKEN_5,
        TOKEN_7,
        TOKEN_16,
        TOKEN_KEY) 
VALUES (INC.DATA_SOURCE,
        INC.OP_DIRECTIVE,
        INC.DD_IMP_FLAG,
        INC.DOB,
        INC.DOD,
        INC.DEATH_VERIFICATION,
        INC.GENDER_PROBABILITY,
        INC.GENDER,
        INC.TOKEN_1,
        INC.TOKEN_2,
        INC.TOKEN_4,
        INC.TOKEN_5,
        INC.TOKEN_7,
        INC.TOKEN_16,
        INC.TOKEN_KEY);
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed to my question!!